# Set element at the vertical middle of a row

Tags: html, css, haml, zurb-foundation

In my grid, I want to do something like this:

```
[main row]
|[columns-10]                     |[columns-2][row]"above img"|
|   Some text                     |                           |
|   here, on                      |[row]            image here|
|   multiple                      |                           |
|   lines                         |[row]           "below img"|
|   ...                           |                           |
```

Notice how the rows in columns-2 are evenly spaced (vertically), relative to the text in columns-10.

Zurb gets me close but the rows inside the columns-2 seem to not be aware of the height of the outer row.

Here's my (haml) code:

```
.row
  .columns.large-10
    %p #{"It does work on all browsers " * 20 }
  .columns.large-2
    .row.right
      .columns.large-12
        above img
    .row.right
      .columns.large-12
        %img{ src: "http://www.gravatar.com/avatar/4d1795fc22c16e533fd1d11fae39fef8.png",
              alt: "Baboon's logo" }
    .row.right
      .columns.large-12
        below img
```

**Edit:** [Here's the JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/XzAQH/2/) try to resize the window and see how the image stays in the top left corner instead of being at mid height of the large text.

Comment: Can you make a http://jsfiddle.net/ demo showing the problem?

Comment: @thirtydot I'm not sure, it has nothing to do with js..

Comment: @Baboon JSFiddle.net is a sandbox for creating examples with HTML/CSS and JS...you can create, save and share a link so that we can inspect your HTML & CSS and tweak to resolve your issue.

Answer (score 0):

You need to include jQuery library in your RoR application and change the HAML code and add a JS file with the below JS code.

HAML Code:

```
.row
  .columns.large-10
    %p #{"It does work on all browsers " * 20 }
  .columns.large-2
    .row.right
      .columns.large-12
        above img
    .row.right#image-container
      .columns.large-12
        %img{ src: "http://www.gravatar.com/avatar/4d1795fc22c16e533fd1d11fae39fef8.png",
              alt: "Baboon's logo" }
    .row.right
      .columns.large-12
        below img
```

JS code with jQuery library:

```
var height=$('#image-container').parent().siblings().height();
var above_height=$('#image-container').siblings().height();
$('#image-container').find('img').height(height-2*above_height)
```

Here is the [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/XzAQH/3/) demo.

Comment: I'm really astonished I need javascript to do something so simple, let alone a 3rd party library..
Nevertheless, it does seem to work, but why is the image stretched?

Comment: Because you typed `the rows inside the columns-2 seem to not be aware of the height of the outer row`, so the image is stretched as per the height of the outer row. Here `the outer row` mean the parent row.

Comment: I just want it to be centered, not stretched =s